# How to ask about a flag of a country?

Tags: sentence-construction, questions

I wonder which of the following questions is grammatically correct:

> 1. What country is this flag?
> 2. What country is this flag of?
> 3. Of what country is this flag?

How would you ask this?

Answer (score 2):

None are grammatical although the second and third are close to grammatical.

> What country is this the flag of?
>
> Of what country is this the flag?

are grammatical. Neither, however, would be idiomatic in speech or informal writing.

> Which country's flag is this?

is probably typical US speech

Answer (score 0):

Alongside Jeff's suggestions in their answer, although I don't think *'Which country's flag is this?'* is typical US speech, you might consider using the following sentence:

> Which country does this flag belong to?

It isn't from any of your options provided, but is widely used.